# Items doesn't show in Recycler View from database

Tags: java, database, sqlite

Hi guys I developed an app that uses database to show words and information about that . in first page I want to show unit number and title but I have problem these are my codes I think I made a mistake:

DBOpenHelper:

```
 public Cursor getList(Int id) {
    String query = "SELECT unit FROM 'ielts'";
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
}
```

TabWord.java:

```
 private void showData() {

    DBOpenHelper db = new DBOpenHelper(getContext());
    db.openDB();



    Cursor cursor = db.getWord(getId());
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String unit_name = cursor.getString(1);
        String unit_number = cursor.getString(2);
        WordItem wordItem = new WordItem(unit_name, unit_number);
        items.add(wordItem);
    }

    }
```

P.S: 
when I add an id number to getList() method it shows successfully only that Item but when I remove it in both java classes I see error

Comment: Which error (show it as properly formatted text in the question)?

Comment: You are selecting one column in your query and then tries to retrieve 2 columns from the response. Isn't the problem obvious or am I missing something here?

Comment: How retrive two columns in my query?

Comment: I wanna get all id not only one